# After importing failed test results build status is succeed in TeamBuild

Tags: automated-tests, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using VSTS (formerly know as VSO), I'm importing test results from a 3rd party testing tool.

This is working fine, however when the imported results have a failure in them, i would expect the build to fail, however it doesn't. As seen below.

[image]

Any advice? this seems like a bug.

Comment: When do you import the test result? During the build process or after the build is completed?

Comment: I had the same issue, so I created http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/12310800--publish-test-results-build-step-with-failed-test feel free to vote for it too

Answer (score 1):

The vNext build pass/fail base on the execution status of each steps in the build definition. It does not check the published test result. You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).